# How to await an async super function in javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

In typescript, let's say I have the following two classes:

```
class X {
    constructor() {
    }

    public async doSomething(): Promise<string> {
        console.log('x')
        return 'x'
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }

    public override async doSomething(): Promise<string> {
        console.log('y before')
        await super.doSomething()
        console.log('y after')
        return 'y'
    }
}
```

and then I run the following:

```
const y = new Y()
y.doSomething()
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
y before
x
y after
```

but instead it is:

```
y before
x
```

almost as if the `await super.doSomething()` is not awaiting anything. I've been mucking around with it and found that if I add some code after `y.doSomething()` the promise does resolve and prints `y after` eventually, adding further support to my theory that it's not awaiting properly.

What's going on here?

Comment: I am getting the expect result https://jsfiddle.net/epascarello/80ov2ec9/

Comment: It would be better to write the promise as `public async doSomething(): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          console.log('x')
          resolve('x');
       });
    }`

Comment: @epascarello how is it better? Why do you mark function as async if you don't use `await`?

Comment: because it is a better test case of a promise....

Comment: These are exactly the same, but yours is less readable

Comment: The OPs is not really an asynchronous operation. lol You can rewrite it as an await

Comment: So the famous question @goastler, what is the actual code.

Comment: Please see comments on @Konrad 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine

```js
class X {
  constructor() {}

  async doSomething() {
    console.log('x')
    return 'x'
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  async doSomething() {
    console.log('y before')
    await super.doSomething()
    console.log('y after')
    return 'y'
  }
}

const y = new Y

y.doSomething()
```

Original `doSomething` probably throws an error hence no `'y after'` output

```js
class X {
  constructor() {}

  async doSomething() {
    console.log('x')
    throw 'e'
    return 'x'
  }
}

class Y extends X {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  async doSomething() {
    console.log('y before')
    await super.doSomething()
    console.log('y after')
    return 'y'
  }
}

const y = new Y

y.doSomething()
```

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, my code is a toy example to demonstrate the problem. At the end of my code I had `process.exit(0)`, which turned out to be part of the problem. I'd missed an `await` elsewhere in my code, meaning a promise wasn't awaited until completion and nodejs was hitting the `process.exit(0)` line before completing the promise. Adding the missing `await` solved everything. So @Konrad 's answer here is correct, it does work, but to anyone else with this problem have a search for missing `await`s!